# Draw line between two nodes not complete in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

My problem is simple I want my line between node(A) and node (B) to be complete (on the top right between the two capacitors). I can't find a clean solution. For info, I'm very new to circuitikz :D

Thank you for your help !

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{circuitikz}[american, voltage shift =0.5]
   \draw (0,0) node[ground](gnd){} to[R=$50\ \Omega$](0,3) --++ (1,0)node[hemt,anchor=G](H){};
   \draw (H.S)  to[R=$3\ k\Omega$](gnd -| H.S) node[ground]{};
   \draw (H.D) to[R=$30\ k\Omega$]($(H.D)+(0,3)$) --++ (2,0)node(A){} to[pC,invert,name=Pc]++(0,-1) --++ (1,0)node[ground]{} to[C,    name=C]++(0,1)node(B){} --++ (1,0)to[C]++(0,-1) --++(-1,0);
   \draw (A) -- (B);
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\draw (A.center) -- (B.center);`

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked !

Comment: Alternatively, use `coordinate` instead of `node`.  An empty node is a rectangle about 0.666em (2 inner sep) wide and high.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is solved by comment, so some off-topic suggestion. I would use integration of `circuitikz` and start drawing scheme at FET transistor:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[siunitx, europeanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american, voltage shift =0.5]
\draw   (0,0)   node[hemt,anchor=G] (H) {}
        (H.G)   -- (H.G |- H.S)
                to[R,a=50<\ohm>]        ++ (0,-2) node[ground]{}
        (H.S)   to[R,l=3<\kilo\ohm>]    ++ (0,-2) node[ground]{}
        (H.D)   to[R=3<\kilo\ohm>]      ++ (0, 2) coordinate (aux1)
                -- ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux2)
                -- ++ (1,0) coordinate (aux3)
                -- ++ (1,0) coordinate (aux4)
        (aux2)  to[pC,invert]   ++ (0,-1) coordinate (aux5)
        (aux3)  to[C]           ++ (0,-1)
        (aux4)  to[C]           ++ (0,-1)
                -- (aux5)
        (aux5 -| aux3) node[ground]{}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

*Note:*
With local options (at `circuitikz`) you overwrite global settings for scheme style. This is not good idea. Better is to stick to global one and with them have uniform style of schemes in whole document. In local settings is sensible define some additional features of scheme, if their really needed.

[image]